# Understanding Ember-Cli Testing

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli

I am trying to get testing set up on an Ember-CLI project, but it currently crashes any browser it is ran in and seems to just freeze when ran from the command line.

From the command line the last line I see is;

```
ok 58 PhantomJS 1.9 - JSHint - routes: routes/projects.js should pass jshint
```

Which is alphabetically the last route file in the directory.

What I would like to know is what the test suite is likely going onto next so I can investigate what could be causing this freeze.

### What I have tried

Googling and reading the associated files inside of `/tests/`, I couldn't see anything obviously out of whack.

### Versions

In case it matters;

- Ember-CLI - `0.0.42`
- PhantomJS - `1.9.7`

Comment: have you run `ember test --server`?

Comment: There are many reasons for freezing tests. Some time ago I had problems with the Ember run loop. So do you use some additional javascript libraries (e.g. Leaflet, or similar)? Also you should look at the `JSHint` warning. Maybe there is some syntax problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was one of the next tests it was hitting (a test created by us) that was throwing an error that was seemingly getting caught somewhere and not displayed.

Rewriting the offending tests (they were written for an earlier version of Ember-CLI, which may have something to do with it) fixed the issue.